# Schedule the Mulitple Local Notification using $cordovaLocalNotifications

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have done the local notification for single time which is triggering perfectly on the time but 
I want multiple notification to be placed, that means, same title,message with different timing.
Here x,y,z are the random number which i am generating, 
In the same way timedate1,timedate2,timedate3 which are dates. Below is my code

But i am not getting any notifications for these.

```
  $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule([{
                        id:x,
                        title: $scope.medicine.medicinename,
                        message: $scope.medicine.medicinename,
                        sound:'file://takemedicin.mp3',
                        autoCancel: true,
                        at:timedate1
                    },{
                        id:y,
                        title: $scope.medicine.medicinename,
                        message: $scope.medicine.medicinename,
                        sound:'file://takemedicin.mp3',
                        autoCancel: true,
                        at:timedate2
                    },{
                        id:z,
                        title: $scope.medicine.medicinename,
                        message: $scope.medicine.medicinename,
                        sound:'file://takemedicin.mp3',
                        autoCancel: true,
                        at:timedate3
                    }])
```

Also i want to placed the timing with different dates like from date and to date like 28-4-2017 to 30-4-2017 at time 12.30pm,12.31pm,12.32pm.

In single notification its triggering for current date, but for next date that is 29-4-2017 it not working. If any help, will be great help for me.